# MySQL needed to download in order to compile from source?

Tags: mysql, installation, tar, slackware

I have Slackware 13.1 and due to some bugs on the current version of the MySQL it comes with, I have to upgrade it. Since Slackware does not have 5.5 and I am upgrading I have decided to go with 5.5.x.

I have tried downloading the generic and non generic tarball but none have the `./configure; make; make install` available.

Could some one explain to me what is the process to build the MySQL from tarball or if there is still a version with `./configure` that I can use with SlackBuild script to build it ?

SlackBuild script:

http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/slackware/slackware64-13.37/source/ap/mysql/mysql.SlackBuild

Comment: Do you remember which bugs you were experiencing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configure and make commands are development tools that you must install separably from building mysql.  To build mysql, you almost certainly need the standard set of development tool, autoconf, gnu make, gcc, glib, and you almost certainly need a few dozen various libraries, and the appropriate headers.

I know a Debian requires these packages installed to build the mysql binaries.

> libc6-dev, gcc, g++, make, libtool,
>   procps, file, libncurses5-dev, perl,
>   libwrap0-dev, zlib1g-dev,
>   libreadline-dev, psmisc, chrpath,
>   automake1.9, gawk, bison

If you haven't built packages before then you may find it much easier to just going with the generic mysql binary.  [Installing MySQL from Generic Binaries on Unix/Linux](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/binary-installation.html)

- Go to http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/#downloads
- Select 'Linux - Generic'

Comment: well I just want the tar.gz that I can use together with SlackBuild script, there is one in there but it is an older version and doesn't help me as it is bugged too.

Comment: If you don't have the development tools installed then you cannot run the script to build anything.

Comment: they were installed by default on the installation, i will check the links out thanks.

Comment: thanks but the link is just for installing the binaries and I am looking into compiling it to create a package I can actually use with SlackBuilds to make the pkg file.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is one of those HUGE frameworks that has many dependencies...  Unless you are comfortable at finding & resolving those dependencies... you probably should stick with one of the many binary releases.  (one such from here: http://pkgs.org/package/mysql#slackware-13.1)

Comment: problem is those have a bug and are not usable for my needs hence why I am looking forward to 5.5

Comment: sorry... didn't' realize that page didn't include a 5.5 for slackware.